# What is "skat"?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I have been reading a report of a mining accident involving a *skat* conveyor. But I can't find out what the skat conveyor is conveying. I have found some references to a *[card game](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skat)*:-

> 1 :  a three-handed card game played with 32 cards in which players
> bid for the privilege of attempting any of several contracts
>
> 2 :  a
> widow of two cards in skat that may be used by the winner of the bid

but one could hardly ship that around on a conveyor. Urban Dictionary has an alternative definition, about which the less said the better.

So, in a mining context, what is *skat*?

Comment: While *skat* is not very common, I suggest you consider some of the older meanings of *scat*, spelled with a *c*. There are some that mean treasure or money, or tribute paid. The OED has like 6 different headword entries all for the noun *scat*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be the model name of a mining conveyor ([Link](http://www.bwf.co.in/products-mining-mining-chain-conveyor.asp?links=pr1b) - scroll to table, first line).

Here is a [PDF document](http://www.dtic.mil/cgi-bin/GetTRDoc?Location=U2&doc=GetTRDoc.pdf&AD=ADA371657) with the mention of an accident with "Skat" conveyor in mining.

Answer (score 4):

Google Books finds only [one result for "**skat conveyor**"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22skat%20conveyor%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (where it's a trade/model name), but there are [11,700 instances of "**slat conveyor**"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22skat%20conveyor%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#psj=1&q=%22slat%20conveyor%22&tbm=bks) (alluding to the ["slatted"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BVwwVMXDoGo) type of conveyor belt).

Given **K** is next to **L** on most English keyboards, I'd say OP's example is probably a typo.

Comment: +1. [Slat conveyors](http://www.mastechmfg.com/Slat.htm) appear to be similar to conveyor belts, except that rather than using one long belt between the wheels on either end, they use a series of thin rectangular slats that run across the width of the conveyor. I'm pretty sure I've seen these things in mines in old images and movies, so this is almost certianly what happened.

Answer (score 3):

*[SKAT PACK](http://www.itequipment.com/products.php?product_id=15)*

> Skat Pack units are devices which convert a given section of transporter into a live (non-accumulating) zone.  These zones move the pallet above them at double the normal conveyor line speed.  Skat packs provide quick, positive movement of the pallet(s) passing over them.  They permit pallet [separation] of pallets which are close packed in queue, and allow more rapid evacuation of work areas.  Pallets held in queue must not rest on skat packs, since these areas are positively driven.

Perhaps that matches what you read about, if not the conveyor systems brand/model name "SKAT".

Answer (score 1):

It couldn't have been a [*skate* conveyor](https://www.google.com/search?q=skate+conveyor)?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. I think this is probably it, but a good answer would expand on it and not simply link to a Google search!

Comment: Do they use skate conveyors in mines? Most of the time I think its the mining products that get put on conveyors, and those would have to travel uphill.

Answer (score 1):

Skats are metal objects that end up in the Run of Mine (ROM). ROM is the material from the pit or from undergorund. Skats may be broken toothes from loaders etc. A magent is used on the conveyor system to collect these peices of metal before they do damage to the milling plant. Your skat conveyor moves the skats from the magnet to a skat bunker most likely. Where it is then disposed of. Hope that helped

Answer (score 0):

scat / skat is animal feces in the wilderness.  Would 'skat conveyor' refer to transport of waste products from the mining or processing of the raw material?.